# Uncommited transactions when recycling IIS

Tags: sql-server, iis

Here's an overview of the problem:
There's a scheduled job that runs every day at 3 AM that recycles IIS pool.
During that time, the users face login issues (and some related issues).

I am trying to troubleshoot. I got to know about uncommitted transactions in DB.
According to my understanding, when IIS application pool gets recycled, a new worker process is created. So, this would mean, that the user will need to re-authenticate himself. 
Doubt: Will the connection pool be cleared when IIS is restarted?

Assuming that the DB connection pool is not cleared, the same old connection which was not closed will be used to access the DB. Since it's a stale connection (Not sure what it's called), it will not be able to connect with the DB. Right?

The application starts working after 1-2 hours automatically.

I'm guessing that the un-committed transaction would have been killed by then?

Please advise me if I'm heading in the correct direction.

Thank you.

Comment: The connection pool has nothing to do with IIS. It doesn't care where the connection comes from. Your question is all over the place though. You aren't doing things like running transactions across multiple page loads or something evil like that are you? In the web world transactions need to be scope to a single page load or you can run into all sorts of issues.

Comment: Let's assume that it's a single page transaction. 
I accept that the question is pretty vague. I wish I could provide more details.
So, IIS has got nothing to do with connection pool. So, if we recycle IIS, the session that were established would go away and we'll need new session/connection to DB. Wouldn't that lead to issues? (Something related to un-committed transactions?)

Comment: The DB connection doesn't go anywhere. Even if you reset IIS the current statement will complete because it was already sent to the database. Now if you have transactions at play they will remain in an uncommitted state until the connection pool closes that connection and any transactions would be rolled back. During that time you might have problems reading data because the data is locked due to an uncommitted transaction.